# VideoJS no poster image when Offline with HTML5 Application Cache

Tags: video.js, html5-appcache, offline-caching, application-cache

The poster image with video.js does not display when I'm offline with AppCache. I've included the poster image URL in the HTML5 application cache manifest file, but when I go offline (disconnect from the network completely), the poster image does not display on the video instance. I am able to play the video successfully by pressing the visible play button, but prior to pressing the play button, there is no poster image. Everything else on the page that is in the application cache works 100% except for this. The application cache confirms that it has successfully cached and stored the poster image when viewing the application cache items on the page with the browser inspector or chrome://appcache-internals/, but the poster image is only visible when I'm online. Is there anything that I'm missing?